# How to convert A4 size postscript to pdf in Linux

Tags: linux, pdf, conversion, postscript

I am trying to convert A4-sized PS documents to PDF.  I am using PS2PDF, but it clips off the right side of the (landscape) page.  Some googling has revealed that ps2pdf always crops to letter-sized pages by default.  I found the option `-dEPSFitPage`, but it doesn't seem to work on my PS; the output is still clipped.  How can I make the output PDF be the correct size?

Comment: Could you post the ps file somewhere so we can try some things?

Comment: I remember that for some landscape PS files I have to use the `-dAutoRotatePages=/All` option. Worth a try?!

Comment: @terdon - Sure, thanks!  http://fazjaxton.net/files/LEDMatrix.ps

Comment: @mpy - I gave that a try, but it didn't help with clipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-g` switch in this way:

```
ps2pdf -g5950x8410 file.ps output.pdf
```

Add a 0 after the needed width and height. So, for instance, to have an A4 sized pdf page (595x841 points), you end up with 5950 and 8410 for width and height, respectively.

Comment: For reference, here is a list of different paper sizes in points: http://www.gnu.org/software/gv/manual/html_node/Paper-Keywords-and-paper-size-in-points.html